# Add zero to incomplete number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with number data. But some number is incomplete (the zero is not recognize). For example I have 33.3 but it should be 33.300 (thirty three thousand three hundred). Or I have 200.22 but it should be 200.220 (two hundred thousand two hundred and twenty). How to automatically add zero to the incomplete number?

Comment: You should use comma(```,```) instead of period(```.```)

Comment: Change the cells formatting. Select the range of cells that require the correct formatting, Right click on a cell within this range, click on 'Format Cells...' within the 'Number' tab under 'Category' select 'Number' and then change 'Decimal places:' to 3

Comment: Use custom cell formatting with `0.000`.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Before you paste (write) the initial data into the worksheet you should format the column as `Text` and add another column where you will retrieve the numbers with a formula e.g. =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")) and finally format the new column with a thousand separator which is probably a comma in your case. Additionally, you could copy/paste values and delete the initial column. To get a more accurate answer, you should consider adding more detail (on how you're acquiring the data) and some sample data to your post.

Comment: Did you type these values into Excel yourself?  Or did you open a text files (like a CSV file) with Excel and let Excel guess how to convert the text in the file into cells in the spreadsheet?  Are you sure you have set your language settings in Excel or your computer to one where periods mean thousands groupings instead decimal point?

Answer (score 0):

Soln to your Q under 2 possible (exhaustive) scenarios:

**1) You can identify/know which numbers are 'incomplete':**

- Isolate, multiply by 100
- Identify, renter

**2) You don't know which number have been 'mis-translated' during capture of your *soi-disant* data:

- Pat on the back & good luck - you need to go back to the export / data capture mechanism to ensure this is operating correctly...

E.g. if you're importing data from SAS / SQL say, then you could format the numbers at source before importing in using, for instance:

```
DECLARE @BigNumber BIGINT
SET @BigNumber = 1234567891234

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,@BigNumber),1), '.00','')
```

(courtesy [SQLMatters](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Formatting%20a%20number%20with%20thousand%20separators.aspx))